# UI elements indicating correctness of textual user input

Tags: forms, icons, feedback, errors

Which symbols are suitable to indicate that something is "verified" or simply correct? As far as i know, a (green) tick is the obvious choice. An alternative is a thumbs up-icon which seems to be widely understood.

In short, these are the popular ways to show correctness afaik:

- green check mark
- thumbs up
- smiley
- green borders around a input field
- writing out words like "correct", "ok" etc.

What are alternative ways to show, that some "stuff" is correct? Notice that i don't want to indicate that some progress has been made.

I'm about to build a UI where i need to indicate for two distinct things, that they are correct. But i don't want to use the same kind of symbol for these different functionalities. Maybe there are different ways to do it, not icon based?!

## Edit:

To be more specific, i want to give feedback after a user solved a question via typing text in a textfield.
There are no UI elements being enabled or disabled by the actions of the user. I just wan't to to inform the user if his answer was correct or not.

Problem: The question itself asked can be verified or not. These are the two distinct kinds of correctness i'am talking about.

More general advice how to handle this is also appreciated.

Comment: This is not a "what is an icon meaning [x]" question. There are other ways to effectively communicate visually with a user besides just icons. Please consider that this question might be within the scope of this site before just seeing the word "icon" and voting to close as a knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: I agree with @maxathousand , sometimes I feel this *"let's close everything"* trend is getting out of hand, this question is clearly within UX.SE's scope

Comment: @rinderwahn When you say "to show that some 'stuff' is correct", what kind of "verification" are you talking about? For example, "verifying" a person's address is valid is pretty different than "verifying" that a user has permission to perform an action (this term is often used loosely in everyday speech). Could you expand on your use case? What kinds of "two distinct things" and what does "correct" mean? What are the "different functionalities" you mention? This all could have an impact on what kind of feedback makes the most sense.

Comment: @maxathousand: "For example, 'verifying' a person's address is valid is pretty different than 'verifying' that a user has permission to perform an action" - is it? In both cases, it seems to me, we are talking about a boolean result, which indicates whether the verification was successful within the margin of error (i.e. how sure we can be about the verification result) imposed by the subject matter.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well, yes, from an implementation point of view, you're right. However, I'm talking about the user's point of view. These boolean results look pretty different--an invalid address might highlight an input field in red and/or provide an error message, while the lack of permissions might disable a button and provide a helpful tooltip explaining their permissions are not sufficient. They both are ways of showing *something is wrong*, but they communicate it very differently to the user.

Comment: @maxathousand: I was talking from a user's point of view, too (the underlying implementations in the two cases might be quite different). Based upon the question, I figure an explicit indication of the "validation results" is deemed necessary by the OP in any case, so merely disabling something seems to be ruled out. Thus, I was thinking of a permission check that the user is aware of (e.g. when issuing a command towards a remote component, which can only then check whether the action is allowed and return some appropriate feedback).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Without knowing more about the specific use case, it's hard (impossible?) to know what kind of pattern is appropriate. (However, I would say that disabling UI elements for functions that are currently unavailable *is* showing the result of some validation...)

Comment: I've edited the post but now imo it's almost too specific - if someone else runs in a similar problem maybe it won't be a help (this is what stackexchange is about, right?!). That's why i've asked the question in more abstract way. Also "_merely disabling something seems to be ruled out_" is correct @maxathousand.

Comment: I still feel your question is too abstract to get any meaningful answers. You've listed commonplace UI/UX methods for conveying correctness, why not just use one? Please explain (in detail, if possible) the "two distinct things" and why a single, commonplace correctness indicator won't work for both.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely not a preferred choice since it takes up more real estate, isn't internationalized, and would take more cognition, but you could also print the word:

[image]

Comment: This could work since i want to give feedback after a user answered a question. Indeed it's not chic, but it would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your scenario, but I would attach a `keyup` listener to the input field using JavaScript, and on each keyup, check the answer for correctness. If it's not correct, do nothing. If it is correct, set the border color of the input field to green, and optionally display a green check mark to the left or right of it, depending on how your UI is set up.

Comment: Ofc this would be work. It's the obvious way to do it. But that's not the whole problem. The actual problem is, that on the very same page, i need an additional indicator for correctness, but in a different context. I'm simply looking for other universally accepted ui elements to show "this one is correct/reliable/verified...". If i use a check mark here, what other kind of symbol, text etc. can i use to tag an other piece of information as correct? I don't want to use the same symbol in a different context.